# How to wait until page auto scroll completed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoscroll

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021547/using-python-selenium-to-click-on-next-page-with-while-loop/41023013) issue, I want to know if there is a way to wait until page auto scroll completed?

The problem is that when you click on the "Next" (`"Volgende"`) button on pagination (`URL` is https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht) for the first time `webdriver` redirects you to the next page and automatically scroll up to the top of page. So if to execute

`WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Volgende')))` 
again, just after redirection, `webdriver` will find button, but click on some other element as focus moves up for about a second.

For now only solution to keep clicking "Next" button until last page reached is to use `time.sleep`:

```
while True:
    try:
        click_icon = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Volgende')))
        click_icon.click()
        time.sleep(2)  # to wait until page scrolled
    except:
        break
```

but it's obviously not the best idea...

P.S. Also I wonder if there is a possibility to disable page auto scroll feature. Switching `general.autoScroll` to `False` in `Firefox` `about:config` doesn't make any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html contains element with tag `<main>` that receives attribute `style` when the page is not scrolled all the way up. I suggest you wait until the tag **doesn't** have this attribute

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'main:not([style*="margin-top"])')))
```

Comment: For those who need to achieve the same with Playwright:
` .page.waitForSelector("<selector>", { timeout: 5000 });`